# Retrieve groups-only from a replace function

Tags: javascript

I am using named groups in a replacement method, and I want to only work with that groups object, as it may have a variable number of capture groups. As an example:

```js
function reFunc(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, offset, string, groups) {
    console.log('*****', groups);
}
"Bob Jones is the mayor of Dallas.".replace(/(?<first>\w+) (?<last>\w+) is the (?<position>\w+) of (?<city>\w+)/, reFunc);
"Bob Jones is the mayor of Dallas, Texas.".replace(/(?<first>\w+) (?<last>\w+) is the (?<position>\w+) of (?<city>\w+), (?<state>\w+)/, reFunc);
```

Is there a way to just ignore everything except the groups in the replacement function, for example something like:

```
function reFunc(..., groups) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture all arguments with either the rest parameter syntax or using the `arguments` reference, and then take the last entry from that:

```js
function reFunc(...groups) {
    groups = groups.pop();
    console.log(groups);
}
"Bob Jones is the mayor of Dallas.".replace(/(?<first>\w+) (?<last>\w+) is the (?<position>\w+) of (?<city>\w+)/, reFunc);
"Bob Jones is the mayor of Dallas, Texas.".replace(/(?<first>\w+) (?<last>\w+) is the (?<position>\w+) of (?<city>\w+), (?<state>\w+)/, reFunc);
```